# error with redux form using fileInput

Tags: file, reactjs, redux, redux-form

form for making for forms and it works very well but when i have a file input it adds a value prop to the file input and it causes this error on the dom

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.(…)**

is there a way for me to prevent the redux-form from adding the value prop to the file input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redux-form` doesn't particularly play well with file upload inputs. I recommend using `react-dropzone` for that and keeping it separate from your `redux-form` form.

Comment: Hi Erik you mean like use whatever implementation and then push the values to redux-form with change(field:String, value:any) : Function ?